# Ошибка при смене mac-адреса

Tags: linux, сеть, router

Пытаюсь сменить mac- адрес на роутере через telnet. Ввожу команду:

```
ifconfig eth0 hw ether 02:01:02:03:04:08
```

в ответ всегда получаю

```
device or resource busy
```

Что я делаю не так? Спасибо.

Comment: а вы отключили интерфейс перед выполнением этой команды? алгоритм: отключить интерфейс, изменить адрес, включить интерфейс. `ip link set dev eth0 down; ip link set dev eth0 address xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx; ip link set dev eth0 up`

Comment: Да, я пытал проделать то что Вы предлагаете, но после команды ifconfig eth0 down у меня падает telnet и не на какие команды роутер не отвечает

Comment: попробуйте выполнить все три действия одной командой, как в моём примере. p.s. 15 лет назад сетевая подсистема linux была кардинально переписана и для управления ею написана программа `ip`. программа `ifconfig` сохраняется лишь по традиции и, в частности, работает не всегда корректно.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Что в переводе означает: "Устройство или ресурс занят".

Перезагрузите роутер и попробуйте снова.

Comment: Пробовал уже несколько раз - не помогает

Comment: Модель роутера?

Comment: asus  RT-N12VP   P.S. через админку mac адрес меняется без проблем

Comment: Тогда либо неверная команда (возможны ошибки заполнения, например на некоторых устройствах MAC адрес вбивается без двоеточий или через дефисы). Либо кривая прошивка, что на роутерах SOHO сегмента встречается довольно часто.

Comment: Странно прошивка заводская стоит, пробовал через тире тоже не помогает. Имеет смысл в тех. поддержку звонить?

Comment: Я бы с этого и начал. Либо на форуме у них пост оставить.

Comment: Позвольте нам [продолжить обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/24176/discussion-between---and-z668).

Comment: @Никола Кривошея, да тут собственно нечего обсуждать. Все и так понятно. Остальное зависит от вас. В любом случае обратитесь в саппорт.